# Reverse an arraylist recursively for a specific range of elements

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

```
public static void reverse(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int temp = numbers.get(start);
        numbers.set(numbers.indexOf(start), numbers.get(end));
        numbers.set(numbers.indexOf(end), temp);
        reverse(numbers, start + 1, end - 1);
    }
}
```

I am trying to recursively reverse elements in an array list. However sample outputs like: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` from `1-3` returns `[4, 2, 2, 4]` not: `[1, 4, 3, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
numbers.set(numbers.indexOf(start), numbers.get(end));
numbers.set(numbers.indexOf(end), temp);
```

to

```
numbers.set(start, numbers.get(end));
numbers.set(end, temp);
```

`start`, `end` are the indices in the list where you want to swap values. You shouldn't call `indexOf` to get you the index. `indexOf` gives you index of first occurrence of the value you pass in.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

You are working too hard. No need to write your recursive `reverse` method.

Modifying a view on a portion of the list affects the original list.

```
Collections
.reverse(                                // Re-ordering a sublist view affects the original list.
    numbers                              // Your modifiable list of objects (Integer objects in your case). 
    .subList( 1 , 3 + 1 )                // Specify your desired subset that needs reversing, to get a view backed by the original list. Use zero-based index numbers. Add one as the ending is exclusive.
) ;
```

## `List::subList`

The result of calling [`List::subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) is a view based directly on that portion of the original list. If you change the original list, you change the sub-list view.

More importantly for our purpose here, if you change the sub-list view, you change the original. So let’s reverse just the subview to affect the original.

Of course this only works on a [modifiable `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodifiable) such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

## `Collections.reverse`

To reverse the list, call utility method [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)).

In these two lines of code, we make a `List`, grab a view onto a portion of that list, reverse the elements in that portion, and thereby affect the original list.

```
List < Integer > numbers = new ArrayList <>( List.of( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ) );
Collections.reverse( numbers.subList( 1 , 3 + 1 ) ) ;
```

Two things about the `subList` method:

- It annoyingly takes arguments that are zero-based index numbers rather than ordinal numbers.
- It is Half-Open, meaning the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So we must add one to the index of the last element we want to include.

## Example usage

Try that code again, but add calls to dump the list to console.

```
List < Integer > numbers = new ArrayList <>( List.of( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ) );
System.out.println( "numbers = " + numbers );

Collections.reverse( numbers.subList( 1 , 3 + 1 ) ) ;
System.out.println( "numbers = " + numbers );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/o2fnbH).

> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> numbers = [1, 4, 3, 2]

Comment: Why do you want to sort ? all the OP wants is to reverse the list between two indices.

Comment: @SomeDude I failed to realize that part. I was too focused on the example data. Revised. Thank you.

Comment: If the “recursion” wouldn’t have been a requirement, this should have been the accepted answer.